# how to use cron to kill a running python script and restart it again?

Tags: process, cron

I have a mac system. I want my program to run for almost a week. However, every four hours or so I want my script to be killed and get restarted. How can I achieve this using cron?

Does cron run in the background or should I let the terminal open and not close it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your cron file:

```
0 * * * * kill -9 `ps -aux|grep {{PROCESS_NAME}}|grep -v grep|awk '{print $2}'` && sh {{PROCESS_NAME.sh}}
```

this command will find you process by name `{{PROCESS_NAME}}` and kill it and restart it by executing `sh {{PROCESS_NAME.sh}}`.

Answer (score 1):

This is assuming you know how to start and stop your script from the command-line.

```
0 */4 * * * command_to_stop && command_to_restart
```

In that case, [the crontab syntax](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?crontab(5)) is

m h d m dow command

The `*/4` tells cron to run every four hours, at 0:00, 4:00, ...